# Microsoft Graph - DELETE onlineMeeting/{Id} doesn't delete the meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

DELETE [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{Id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/onlineMeetings/%7BId%7D)

The DELETE operation is successful and I do get a 404 if I try to GET the onlineMeeting I just deleted, but I can still open the meeting URL and join it online.

If I also delete the calendar event and join the meeting by pasting the join URL in the browser, and I can still join it.

***Why doesn't it actually DELETE the onlineMeeting?***  I deleted a meeting hours ago, and I can still join it.

p.s. same thing in the v1.0 call, it doesn't delete the onlineMeeting

Comment: A year later and still no updates. I can still recreate this now.